# How to construct a hashtable of dynamic type

Tags: java, hashmap, runtime, hashset

I have a function which has to 2 lists of different types a parameter inputs. To optimize, I want to create a HashSet  / Hashtable (either of them ) of type of smallest list. Is there a way in a java to decide the `type of Set` at runtime ?

Current code:

```
   public static void innerJoinHash(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList) {
        if (sportsMans.size() < sportList.size()) {
            Set<SportsMan> set = new HashSet<SportsMan>();
        } else {
            Set<Sport> set = new HashSet<Sport>();
        }
    }
```

What I want to do:

```
public static void innerJoinHash(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList) {
    Set< // some magic //> set       
       if (sportsMans.size() < sportList.size()) {
         set = new HashSet<SportsMan>();
    } else {
        set = new HashSet<Sport>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would want to do this? Why can't you just do some logical test, pick the right type of set, and then by on your way using the super type?

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? You are creating `Set<SportsMan>` OR `Set<Sport>` but what you want to do with it ? All the generic `Set` operations will be available to any of those.

Comment: Sorry guys - edited my question

Comment: You didn't answer the question: what will you do with this set after it's been created? Your code creates a set and throws it away.

Comment: I would use it to do a join operation with the larger set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Java Generics. `Set<E> customSet=new HashSet<E>();`

That is a way you can use assign data type in run time.

```
  public static void innerJoinHash(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList) {
  Set set = new HashSet();  
  if (sportsMans.size() < sportList.size()) {
        set.addAll(sportsMans)
    } else {
        set.addAll(sportList);
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Santosh I think this is the answer he is looking for

Comment: This is using raw `Set` and it doesn't make sense to use it when you are using Generics.

Comment: Why use `innerJoinHash(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList)` at all. Why not simply `innerJoinHash(List sportsMans, List sportList)`

Comment: @Santosh you can do as you wish, I just change Set what asked by OP

Comment: @Santosh I agree with what you are saying.  As per my answer.  Why use generics at all. Set<E> will buy you nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The "// some magic //" you're looking for is the most specific common supertype of `Sport` and `SportsMan`. I.e., if both classes implement or extend a common interface, you can use that. Otherwise, it will be `Object`:

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>(
    sportsMan.size() < sportsList.size()
    ? sportsMan : sportsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understand you question, but what is wrong this this approach?

```
    Set myset = new HashSet();
    myset.add("Hello");
    myset.add(new Long(1));
```

If you dumb it down by using Set or Set you are getting no benefits of generics.

Answer (score 0):

Create the type of Set as Object and on the run time while retrieval you can always cast the object into required data type.

OR

```
public static void innerJoinHash(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList) {    
       if (sportsMans.size() < sportList.size()) {
      Set set = new HashSet<SportsMan>();
    } else {
       Set set = new HashSet<Sport>();
    }
}
```